# dplyr and lubridate chain crashing r

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I'm stuck as to why the following code is crashing R on my machine (both in rstudio and the basic R gui)  - any help would be very much appreciated!

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)


dates <- data.frame(date = seq(ymd('2015-01-01'),ymd_hms('2019-06-20 23:00:00'),by = "hour"))

# Run this section a few times (simulate many calls in a shiny app)
for(i in 1:10)
  test_df <- dates %>%
    mutate(month = month(date),
           year = year(date))
```

My session info:

```
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lubridate_1.3.3 dplyr_0.4.2    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] assertthat_0.1 DBI_0.3.1      digest_0.6.8   magrittr_1.5   memoise_0.2.1  parallel_3.1.3 plyr_1.8.3     R6_2.0.1       Rcpp_0.11.6   
[10] stringi_0.4-1  stringr_1.0.0  tools_3.1.3
```

Update:

I tried re-installing Rcpp then dplyr, but still ran into the same issue.  Furthermore, I was also able to recreate the same issue on my mac.  What I ended up doing, was rolling back a version of dplyr (0.4.1), restarting, and things are now working as to be expected.   I checked the rstudio log file after a crash and saw this:

```
LOGGED FROM: void {anonymous}::rCleanup(bool) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\session\SessionMain.cpp:2311
18 Jun 2015 21:20:22 [rsession-cmohan] ERROR r error 4 (R code execution error) [errormsg=Error: cannot allocate vector of size 4.0 Gb|||]; OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::r::exec::{anonymous}::evaluateExpressionsUnsafe(SEXP, SEXP, SEXPREC**, rstudio::r::sexp::Protect*) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\r\RExec.cpp:149
```

Comment: runs ok with `lubridate_1.4.0.9500`, `dplyr_0.4.2`

Comment: Downloaded lubridate_1.4.0.9500 and re-ran.  It worked the first and second time I ran the code above, but then hung up on the third.  Unfortunately I didn't get an error, R just crashed.

Comment: @Khashaa for example if I run this code, it prints 5 times before it crashes:`> library(lubridate)
> for(i in 1:20){
+   test_df <- dates %>%
+     mutate(month = month(date),
+            year = year(date))
+   print(memory.size())
+ }
[1] 42.38
[1] 42.33
[1] 42.88
[1] 42.57
[1] 42.57`

Comment: The code works perfectly for me, I've run it at least 10 times in few seconds and no one error.

Comment: Try re-installing Rcpp and then re-instaling dplyr.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I updated part of the question, any thoughts on the log file error?

Comment: So, after upgrading to R 3.2.1 on OS X 10.10.3 and using lubridate 1.4.0.9500 & dplyr 0.4.2.9000 I can get this to crash consistently in latest RStudio (dailies) _and_ in R.app. Methinks this warrants a github issue on one of the pkgs, prbly lubridate as it doesn't crash when I use `format` for the conversions.

Comment: I agree, and I am getting the same problem!